# No visible @interface for 'JSQSystemSoundPlayer' declares the selector 'playSoundWithFilename:fileExtension:'

Tags: ios, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

This is where my build fails in JSQSystemSoundPlayer. I cannot get around this.

```
if (asAlert) {
    [[JSQSystemSoundPlayer sharedPlayer] playAlertSoundWithFilename:fileName fileExtension:kJSQSystemSoundTypeAIFF];

}
else {
    [[JSQSystemSoundPlayer sharedPlayer] playSoundWithFilename:fileName fileExtension:kJSQSystemSoundTypeAIFF];
}
```

Comment: Have you included the appropriate header file?

Comment: Yes, The library was as it is downloaded and added to project(not via pod though). in bridging header, I did import JSQSystemSoundPlayer        #import "JSQSystemSoundPlayer.h"

Comment: Do you need a completion handler? I can't see the same method defined here: https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQSystemSoundPlayer/blob/develop/JSQSystemSoundPlayer/JSQSystemSoundPlayer/JSQSystemSoundPlayer.h

Comment: In fact, looking at the history, the methods without completion blocks have now been removed.

Comment: so you mean, I should re-download and add the JSQSoundPlayer or complete JSQMessagesVC to the latest ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the header file, I think you need to include a completion block (which you can set to `nil` if you don't want anything doing).

```
if (asAlert) {
    [[JSQSystemSoundPlayer sharedPlayer] playAlertSoundWithFilename:fileName fileExtension:kJSQSystemSoundTypeAIFF completion:nil];

} else {
    [[JSQSystemSoundPlayer sharedPlayer] playSoundWithFilename:fileName fileExtension:kJSQSystemSoundTypeAIFF completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Awesome, worked perfectly. I got your point from your 2nd comment to add completion block, but was wondering what to add in the block. I'm such a amateur... Experience wins.